# CSS Border Gainsboro from IE7 to other browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, border, gradient

I have the following CSS for table borders:

```
BORDER-BOTTOM: gainsboro 5px inset;
BORDER-LEFT: gainsboro 1px solid;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: gainsboro;
BORDER-TOP: gainsboro 1px solid;
BORDER-RIGHT: gainsboro inset
```

And in IE7 it produces this border:

[image]

But in any other browser, the result is

[image]

How i reproduce the border that IE7 generates in another browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, it worked fine for me with this code:

```
table{
    border-bottom: gainsboro 5px inset;
    border-left: gainsboro 1px solid;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    border-top: gainsboro 1px solid;
    border-right: gainsboro 5px inset;
}
```

The catch is you hadn't set a width for the right border, and the background color is the same as the solid borders, so you won't see them--they'll blend with the background. Inset borders render with different colors to make them look, well, inset, so they won't blend with the identical background color.

Edited to add-- And sorry you have to work with IE7

Comment: But is there a way to add this dark line in border like ie? I've tried to set width for the border but stills the same. The groove and outset works like a charm, but inset only renders like i want in ie 7.

Comment: Ah sorry-- add 'border-collapse: collapse;'  here's a [**working sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/7up7d18d/)